# Unable to make function to push an array to the redis list in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am using redis list for storing the value for a key in nodeJS. I have made the following function and exported it to another file to make it a api:

```
async function set(id, ...seats) {
    var seatArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++)
    {
        seatArr = seatArr.concat(seats[i]);
    }
    try{
        result = await client.rpush('seats_'+id, ...seatArr);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

}
module.exports = {
    set : set()
};
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
{ ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'rpush' command
    at parseError (/home/shivank/Music/node-app/ticket-booking/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/home/shivank/Music/node-app/ticket-booking/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14) command: 'RPUSH', args: [ 'seats_undefined' ], code: 'ERR' }
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Is your goal to `rpush` for every item in the array? Seems to be two issues, `id` is undefined but this isn't why it's breaking, you can see that there is only one argument being passed to `RPUSH` your `...seatArr` must be empty

Comment: @razki yeah seatArr is empty because I haven't called that function yet. I am just exporting that function. But I want to wait until the function is called. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You are not exproting a function, you are trying to export the result of the function (which files because you didn't provide the params that it needs).

```
module.exports = {
    set : set().   // <<<---- You are executing the function
};
```

but you didn't give it any params so the `id` param is equal to `undefined`.

From your stacktrace:

```
..[ 'seats_undefined' ].. // 'seats_'+id === 'seats_'+`undefined` === 'seats_undefined'
```

#### Solution

```
module.exports = {
    set : set
};
```